# Is there a command line switch to open a specific email/thread with Groupwise?

Tags: groupwise

I would like to be able to open a specific email (using messageid or something like that) when calling grpwise.exe.

Comment: [Using Startup Options](https://www.novell.com/documentation/nm2/nm2_client/data/bs3p66t.html) would suggest the answer is **no**